# Account association bonus not applied?

Tags: support, reputation, association

What is the exact source of the 101 point reputation bonus I get every time I create a linked account on another trilogy/area51 site?

I ask because I currently have linked accounts on 7 sites and all of them but ServerFault have at least 101. My ServerFault score is only 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The breakdown is as follows:

```
1   - Free!!!
100 - Association Bonus if you have more than 200 rep on 1 SE site
```

Try logging out and back in (on Server Fault) to get the association bonus on Server Fault. Alternatively, you can force a reset by selecting *Clear All Associations* on your accounts tab in your user profile.

Comment: Logging out and in won't help; you need to reassociate the account

Comment: Logging in and out doesn't seem to help. @Waiwai How can I reassociate it?

Comment: @Michael Actually, association checks are performed during login.

Comment: Not if the account is already associated; he needs to disassociate them first (which is done through a button on the [accounts](http://serverfault.com/users/17033?tab=accounts) tab)

Comment: Using the clear associations button fixed it. I now have 111 on SU. Thanks guys! @Wai you should post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.