# My Association Bonus was not applied to SuperUser. How do I clear all associations?

Tags: support, status-completed, linked-accounts

I have 10 accounts on Stack Exchange.  When I reached 200 rep on one account, I earned association bonus on 9 of the accounts.  My SuperUser account has not received the bonus.  As suggested in [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/60786/220382), [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84328/220382), and [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88009/220382), I've logged out and logged back in again on SuperUser.  They also suggests to clear the association and then add it again.  However, I do not see a "Clear All Associations" option in the Accounts tab of my Stack Exchange profile.  How do I clear my associations?

Comment: I'll find someone to fix this up for you. Please hold. :)

Comment: Thanks, looks like it's fixed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to a comment by Jeff Atwood on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82871/181695) to a [similar (though not duplicate question)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82866/how-do-i-remove-an-account-association), you can no longer do this and the button has been removed.

It seems your only option is to hope a mod comes along and fixes it or to do as Jeff suggests in another comment and email your issue to Stack Exchange.

Hope that helps. (by the way I checked out your profile its definitely broken for super user) :(